# Dog skin disease

Tags: dogs, veterinarian

my dog has something weird in its skin and i don't know what to do. The vet told me to give him a medicine called amoxil but it didn't help.

Here are some photos[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your time

Comment: i guess your vet prescribed amoxilin it is an antibiotic,i think you need a second opinion from another vet if the treatment did not help your dog.

Comment: and you have to give more information about the dog like the age and gender of your dog how long has it been like this,more details please.

Comment: @trondhansen the dog is male, almost six years old, its a very big dog and he is like this for about a year.

Comment: How long has he been taking Amoxilin?

Comment: He took it for 15 days,then he didn't took it for another 15 and then he took it again for 15 days. The infection reduced but not completely as you can see.